# Finding the dimension of the eigenspace of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, bilinear-form

Given a symmetric, bilinear form $\phi: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $V$ having dimension $n$.

The map is given as $f_b(x)=x+\phi(x,b).b$ where $b \in V$, $b \neq 0$, $f_b: V \rightarrow V$.

This is a sample exam question that demands showing for eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ the dimension of the eigenspace is $n-1$.

I know that I can say $\phi(x,b)=x^T Ab$ but I fail to move on from here to show what is being demanded. Do I have to construct $A$ to show this?

Another idea I had was to show that $f$ has Jordan form and move from there but I am stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that $f_b(x)=x+\phi(x,b)$ is the sum of a vector and a scalar?

Comment: yes the sum part is correct but I did make a mistake forgetting to add the multiplication by b. I have edited the question.